# Javascript: The code works fine on computer but has problem when being applied on Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

I'm designing a "note" section for my blogger posts.

The code is supposed to create 3 child divisions inside the "note-container" which, in order, have the class "takeaway", "vertical-bar" and "note-content" and move the text inside the "note-container" into the "note-content".

My code works fine when being run on with the HTML file on my computer, but when being applied on Blogger, no child divisions were appended. This is my code for the child-appending function:

```
function create_note() {
    let note_container = document.querySelectorAll(".note-container");
    console.log(note_container);
    for (let i = 0; i < note_container.length; ++i){
        let note_content = document.createElement("div");
        note_content.classList.add("note-content");
        note_content.innerText = note_container[i].innerText;
        note_container[i].innerText = "";
        console.log(note_content.innerText);

        let takeaway = document.createElement("div");
        takeaway.innerText = "NOTE";
        takeaway.classList.add("takeaway");
                
        let vertical_bar = document.createElement("div");
        vertical_bar.classList.add("vertical-bar");

        note_container[i].appendChild(takeaway);
        note_container[i].appendChild(vertical_bar);
        note_container[i].appendChild(note_content);
    }
}
create_note();
```

You can activate the code on blogger by putting some text inside a division (in the HTML tab in the post) like this:

```
<div class = "note-container"> Lorem Ipsum </div>
```

This is what it is supposed to look like:
[image: mouse hovering state]

[image: normal state]

[image: applied to blogger]

When I add console.log(note_container) to the code and applied it to blogger, it didn't return anything, as well.

What I could have done wrong?
If you need the full code this is the link: https://github.com/Haiyahhh/Note

Comment: i think blogger doesn't allow you to insert script

Comment: It does tho because I tried it before :)) u can edit the html in the theme section

Comment: Does devtools give any error?

Comment: @TachibanaShin it did. Notice I there is a line in my code where I use console.log(note_container), when I open the file on PC it returned a node list that has 1 note-container, but when I open devtool in the post of my blogspot it did not return anything, probably blogger has something to do with it. As I presented in the question when I open DevTools on my Lưu ý.HTML there were 3 child elements appended, but in there was no child appended when I upload the code onto the blogger page :v If your question meant if there were any errors that Devtools return, I'd say it return no syntax error.